# Why are products called minterms and sums called maxterms?

Tags: boolean, logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

Do they have a reason for doing so? I mean, in the sum of minterms, you look for the terms with the output 1; I don't get why they call it "minterms." Why not maxterms because 1 is well bigger than 0?

Is there a reason behind this that I don't know? Or should I just accept it without asking why?

Comment: I found this question because I had a similar doubt. I wanted to know what the practical application of a maxterm was. The minterm application is very well explained in the link provided by @Rubenelius. However, I can't think of how a maxterm would ever evaluate to true or 1 considering the fact that if there were like 2 or 3 possible maxterms... if 1 evaluated to true the others would definitely evaluate to 0.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The convention for calling these terms "minterms" and "maxterms" does not correspond to 1 being greater than 0. I think the best way to answer is with an example:

Say that you have a circuit and it is described by `X̄YZ̄ + XȲZ`.

"This form is composed of two groups of three.  Each group of three is a 'minterm'.  What the expression minterm is intended to imply it that each of the groups of three in the expression takes on a value of 1 only for one of the eight possible combinations of X, Y and Z and their inverses." http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/elessonshtml/Logic/Logic2.html

So what the "min" refers to is the fact that these terms are the "minimal" terms you need in order to build a certain function. If you would like more information, the example above is explained in more context in the link provided.

Edit: The "reason they used MIN for ANDs, and MAX for ORs" is that:
In **Sum of Products** (what you call ANDs) only one of the minterms must be true for the expression to be true.
In **Product of Sums** (what you call ORs) all the maxterms must be true for the expression to be true.

Comment: Ohhh because there's only 1 possible combination per "term" to be true.. opposed to the X+Y+Z maxterm. I get it. Or did i misunderstand it?

Comment: That is correct. The edit was made to reflect that. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Rubenulis The link is broken... can you please fix it?

Answer (score 11):

```
min(0,0) = 0
min(0,1) = 0
min(1,0) = 0
min(1,1) = 1
```

So minimum is pretty much like logical AND.

```
max(0,0) = 0
max(0,1) = 1
max(1,0) = 1
max(1,1) = 1
```

So maximum is pretty much like logical OR.

Comment: yeah.. but im asking if there's a reason they used MIN for AND/products, and MAX for OR/sum. just incase well someone asks.

Answer (score 2):

In **Sum Of Products** (**SOP**), each term of the SOP expression is called a **"minterm"** because,

say, an **SOP** expression is given as:
*F(X,Y,Z) = X'.Y'.Z + X.Y'.Z' + X.Y'.Z + X.Y.Z*

for this **SOP** expression to be **"1"** or *true* (being a **positive logic**),
***ANY*** of the term of the expression should be 1.
thus the word "minterm".

i.e, **any** of the term (X'Y'Z) , (XY'Z') , (XY'Z) or (XYZ) being **1**, results in **F(X,Y,Z) to be 1**!!
Thus they are called "minterms".

---

On the other hand,
In **Product Of Sum** (**POS**), each term of the POS expression is called a "maxterm" because,

say an **POS** expression is given as: F(X,Y,Z) = (X+Y+Z).(X+Y'+Z).(X+Y'+Z').(X'+Y'+Z)

for this **POS** expression to be "**0**" (because **POS** is considered as a **negative logic** and we consider **0** terms), ***ALL*** of the terms of the expression should be 0. thus the word "max term"!!

i.e for **F(X,Y,Z) to be 0**,
**each** of the terms (X+Y+Z), (X+Y'+Z), (X+Y'+Z') and (X'+Y'+Z) should be equal to "**0**", otherwise F won't be zero!!

---

> *Thus each of the terms in POS expression is called a **MAXTERM (maximum all the terms!)** because all terms should be zero for F to
>   be zero, whereas any of the terms in POS being one results in F to be
>   one. Thus it is known as **MINTERM (minimum one term!)***

Comment: Why should all terms of Maxterm be 0 for the product to the 0? Any of the sums involved in the product would make definitely make the entire product 0... isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that AB is called a minterm is because it occupies the minimum area on a Venn diagram; while A+B is called a MAXTERM because it occupies a maximum area in a Venn diagram. Draw the two diagrams and the meanings will become obvious
Ed Brumgnach

Comment: Why a minus 1? I think my answer is the only one that explains "why" the ANDs are called "minters" while ORs are called "MAXTERMS". All the other answers explain "what" minters and MAXTERMS are.  A combination of variables equating to a 1 or a 0 has nothing to do maximums and minimums.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to think about it.

> A product is called a *minterm* because it has *minimum-satisfiability* where as a sum is called a *maxterm* because it has *maximum-satisfiability* among all practically interesting boolean functions.
>
> They are called *terms* because they are used as the building-blocks of various canonical representations of arbitrary boolean functions.

---

**Details:**

Note that '0' and '1' are the trivial boolean functions.
Assume a set of boolean variables `x1,x2,...,xk` and a non-trivial boolean function `f(x1,x2,...,xk)`.

Conventionally, an input is said to *satisfy* the boolean function `f`,  whenever `f` holds a value of `1` for that input.

Note that there are exactly `2^k` inputs possible, and any non-trivial boolean-function can *satisfy* a minimum of 1 input to a maximum of `2^k -1` inputs.

Now consider the two simple boolean functions of interest: sum of all variables **S**, and product of all variables **P** (variables may/may-not appear as complements). **S** is one boolean function that has *maximum-satisfiability* hence called as *maxterm*, where as **P** is the one having *minimum-satisfiability* hence called a *minterm*.