# Why are sum of minterms equated to 1 and product of maxterms to 0?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have learnt that to convert an expression in the form of a Truth Table to a Sum of Product expressions, we use the concept of minterms. After preparing the truth table we find out which products evaluate to 1 and add those products.

While in the case of Product of Sum expression, we take those sums that evaluate to 0 and take the product of those sums.

I could not understand the logic behind this taking of 0 and 1. In an answer I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593335/why-are-products-called-minterms-and-sums-called-maxterms), I found that POS is considered as a **negative logic**. I could  not understand the concept behind it. What is the real logic behind this?

Answer (score 1):

This is something I was confused with as well. When we write the truth table and see for which cases the value of F evaluates to 1, we get multiple cases. In SOP, ANY of those minterms can be true and the whole Function would be 1 because 1+X=1 This is the intuition behind SOP being positive logic and hence automatically, its complement, POS being negative logic.
Check out this answer for further clarification.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2794909/boolean-algebra-sum-of-products-and-product-of-sums-why-is-the-procedure-def#